# How to get latitude and longitude from Google Places API android in the same response?

Tags: google-places-api, autocompletetextview

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=mykey&components=country:in&input=Pal
```

With the above URL, how do i get latitude and longitude as well along with the other details in the json response?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a two way web service call. Issue is now resolved.

Answer (score -1):

you have to call 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=""&key=mykey

places id which return in autocomplete api